# How is BigQuery Streaming Inserts billed?

Tags: google-bigquery

When using Streaming Inserts to load data to BigQuery, are the data size calculated by the JSON size or the data size in BigQuery storage?
I'm asking since the JSON might be 3 times bigger than the actual data inside.
I've read all Google documentation I found without finding a clear answer.

Comment: AFAIK, it's calculated depending on storage: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#storage

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I've missed that. @Graham Polley

Comment: OK, cool. I'll move my comment to an answer for posterity. if you could accept that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Streaming inserts are billed according to BigQuery's internal storage mechanism. As per the official Google docs:

> Storage pricing is based on the amount of data stored in your tables, which we calculate based on the types of data you store. Streaming Inserts  $0.05 per GB, with individual rows calculated using a 1 KB minimum size.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#storage